# Changes to the DX tag

Tags: discussion, tags

I just edited the tag [dx](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dx). Before, there was no descriptive text associated with it.
https://ham.stackexchange.com/tags/dx/info

If anyone wants to suggest edits, here's the place.

Comment: Looks good to me.